# How do I process numerous files using numerous regex conditions?

Tags: python, function, class, attributes

I want to process the `cna` and `linear_cna` files by reading only lines that do not contain  either `Hugo_Symbol` or `-01`.

```
import os
import re
   
class DataProcessing:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.line = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in data]
        self.data = data

    def read_data(self):
        with open(self.data):
            pass
        return self.line
    
    def read_cna(self):
        # In cna and linear_cna files, skip lines that either begin with "Hugo_Symbol" or "-01"
        for lines in self.line:
            cna_lines = [lines for l in cna if not re.findall(r"^(Hugo_Symbol|[-01])", l)]
            return cna_lines




...continue...


dp_cna = DataProcessing("data_cna.txt")
dp_linear_cna = DataProcessing("data_linear_cna.txt")


dp_cna.read_data()
dp_linear_cna.read_data()
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/testing/main.py", line 24, in <module>
    cna = DataProcessing.read_data("data_cna.txt")
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/testing/main.py", line 14, in read_data
    with open(self.data) as f:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'data'
```

Answer (score 1):

The right way to use your class consists of two steps.

Step 1: Create an *instance* of `DataProcessing` by invoking `__init__`. You do this by declaring `dp = DataProcessing("data_cna.txt")`. You can replace `dp` with any name you want.

Now `dp` is an instance of `DataProcessing`. Its `data` field is set to `"DataProcessing"`. In other words, `dp` remembers the name of the file.

Step 2: Call `read_data` on `dp`. Note that `read_data` has only one parameter, namely `self`, which should not be passed as an argument, meaning it takes no arguments. Therefore, the right way to call `read_data` is just `read_data()`. To call `read_data` on `dp` you do `dp.read_data()`.